# Efficiency of RecyclerView with WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

Does setting `WRAP_CONTENT` for `RecyclerView`'s height will cause all ViewHolders to be created during initialization? If this is the case, does that mean nothing is being "recycled" and it will slow down in devices with low memory?

**UPDATE 1:**
I realized this will happen when you put `RecyclerView` in a `NestedScrollView`. It is needed for my case as I have custom layout to display other than the RecyclerView in my fragment.

Comment: `all ViewHolders `? what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink supposedly if my screen can only display 5 items, recyclerview will only create at max 7 ViewHolders out of the 200 items I have in my adapter. but since if I am having a `wrap_content` height for my recyclerView, doesn't that mean it couldn't tell how many items my screen are capable of displaying?

Comment: even if you have `wrap_content` it doesn't mean that 200 holders will be created: for example if your recyclerview is 1000 pixels tall (height) and each item is at least 20 pixels tall it means that max 52 or so holders will be created

Comment: @pskink but my testing shows otherwise. and I will agree with you if the height is match_parent.

Comment: so 200 holders are created or what?

Comment: it is. hence the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116777/discussion-between-you-qi-and-pskink).